# onesignal Android disable double opt-in

Tags: web, push, onesignal

I would like to avoid the behaviour that was descibed in the blog post https://onesignal.com/blog/web-push-changes-to-chrome-on-android/. In other words I want to show only android native consent without the slide-up permission box. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I found a solution, I set autoRegister to false in the initialization and call OneSignal.registerForPushNotifications() and it shows the native consent dialog without the slide-up dialog.